# Why Axios Sending response in the form of [objects] [object]?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/users/current',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
  },
}).then(response => { console.log(response) })
```

the axios method is sending response in the form of [object] [object]

Comment: Its not axios sending. Its your backend is sending. Can you check what is data format

Comment: It is showing in object format only

Comment: Can you add response in code. What is coming from backend(by checking in network tab)?

Comment: You have typo in your code, it's supposed to be `console.log(response)` not `console.log(Response)`

Comment: Success[object Object] same response I'm getting in network tab @ShubhamVerma

Comment: Then fix in backend. If possible share network tab screenshot

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))`, I think you might have a tight object, but the console print you the response in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Promises it displays object but you can use the data in the object